# How do you find the multivariable limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy}{\sqrt x +\sqrt y }$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy}{\sqrt x+\sqrt y}$ considering domain $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x,y \ge 0, (x,y) \ne 0\}$
I tried using polar coordinates, but the theta function is unbounded. I also tried using the sandwich theorem, but could not find appropriate bounds. How do I approach this question

Comment: $\sqrt x$ is not defined for $x<0$.

Comment: For $x, y \ge 0$ use the inequality $\frac{xy}{\sqrt x+\sqrt y}\le \frac{xy}{\sqrt x}$

Comment: so the equation would be squeezed by $0$ and $\sqrt x y$ and the limit would be $0$ right? Thank you!

Comment: Another way is to use $\sqrt x  + \sqrt y  \ge 2(xy)^{1/4}$ which comes from the inequality between the arithmetic and the geometric means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As "geetha290krm" said: For $x>0,y>0$, you can rewrite as below
$$\frac{xy}{\sqrt x +\sqrt y }
=\frac 12 \frac{2xy}{\sqrt x +\sqrt y }\\0 \le\frac 12(\frac{xy}{\sqrt x +\sqrt y }
+\frac{xy}{\sqrt x +\sqrt y }
)=\frac 12(\frac{y\sqrt{x^2}}{\sqrt x +\sqrt y }
+\frac{x\sqrt{y^2}}{\sqrt x +\sqrt y })\le \\\frac 12(\frac{y\sqrt{x^2}}{\sqrt x  }
+\frac{x\sqrt{y^2}}{\sqrt y })=\frac 12 (y\sqrt x+x \sqrt y)\\=\frac 12 \sqrt {xy}(\sqrt y+\sqrt x) 
$$
and it works for every path near $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$u:=\sqrt{x}, v:=\sqrt{y}$ where $u,v \ge 0;$

Consider

$0 \le u,v <1;$

Numerator : $u^2v^2  \le uv \le (u+v)^2.$

Can you finish?